# c# Exception Thrown at (not in) Constructor

Tags: c#, exception

An exception is being thrown at (not in) a constructor call:

```
controller = new Controller(classInstance);   // Won't let me step in, exception thrown immediately.
```

The exception description is:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLib, Version=1.0.4314.17265, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

`classInstace` isn't null and I cannot step into the constructor. I have never experienced this before. Any idea what this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: this error looks like x86 vs x64 build issue. the constructor of Controller class is not getting called, where do you build your object of type classInstance?

Comment: @DavidePiras: After I changed the target platform option to x86, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (fuslogvw.exe) to see which assembly's being matched to ClassLib. Like Jon Skeet said, it's probably either a corrupted file, a 32 vs/ 64-bit issue, or a weird runtime mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - it can't find the `ClassLib` assembly which presumably contains `Controller` - or one of its dependencies. The `BadImageFormatException` suggests that maybe you've got a broken file (copy failed?) or possibly you're trying to load a .NET 4 assembly into a .NET 2 CLR. (I don't know whether that gives that exception or not, but I wouldn't be surprised.)

You haven't said what kind of project this is, but basically check all of your dependencies.

Comment: It found controller, or the exception would have been thrown upon entering the function referencing its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't load an assembly referenced by the code in the class's constructor.